# Why is my setCallData hook not storing data when attempting to fetch Webflow blogs in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, blogs, webflow

I am trying to fetch some blogs from Webflow into my react app.

The setCallData hook does not seem to be storing data as the callData console.log is undefined. Could someone help?

I tried pretty much anything in my capabilities.

````
const BlogSection = () => {

    const [callData, setCallData] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                accept: 'application/json',
                authorization: 'Bearer 8ea2c9fa8594d39ba34541182ceed3edc0752db7b5a09438dc0a3651116bc4a6'
            }
        };

        const fetchBlogs = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://api.webflow.com/collections/6433ba761ddcb04783f42f94/items', options)
                const json = await response.json()
                setCallData(json.items)
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log("error", error);
            }
        }

        fetchBlogs();

    }, []);

    console.log(callData,'blogs')

    return (
        <>
            {callData ? callData.map((blog) =>{
                return <p>{blog.name}</p>
            }) : null}
        </>
    )
}

export default BlogSection;```
````

Comment: It will certainly log `undefined` on the *first* render, but are you indicating that there is no subsequent re-render?  Or, if there is, it still logs `undefined`?  When you debug, what observed value does `json.items` have when calling `setCallData`?

Comment: @David should'nt the useEffect re-render? like componentDidMount? when using useEffect nothing consoles, if i remove the usEffect then the jason.items is an array of blogs in an object. however the data is not stored in callData even if I use setCallData

Comment: `useEffect` doesn't trigger a re-render, but updating state does.  It's not really clear to me what you mean by the rest of that.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  (Using hard-coded Promise results if the API is not otherwise reachable in the example.)  Failing that, we'll need specific debugging observations about the code shown.  Any errors on the browser console, the observed runtime value of `json.items`, etc.